# How to access response from redirected url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redirect, oauth-2.0

**Problem Statement**

We need to get the third party authentication done, but problem is when we are getting redirected back to our domain (`https://flow-qa.mobileaware.com/unified/auth/redirect?code=VLTwn9`) after successfully login to third party portal, in addition to getting `code(in query string)`, we are also getting some user related information in response. As of now, i don't have clue for `how to get access to this response`.

Feel free to post a comment if more information is required.

Comment: Are you doing this in the browser or at your server?  Does 3rd party auth require white list url?

Comment: @zipzit I am doing this on browser. Server side implementation is not in my hand right now. Just want to make sure can i grab the response before going to server guys. As per my understanding, as soon as redirect response will come, browser will make a request to redirect_url (which loads the react app) and at this point we will loose response body

Comment: I’m assuming you are doing an Ajax post request to the 3rd party authentication server?  It would be nice to see an extract of your code. It’s not clear to me exactly what your problem is.

Comment: I realize this next suggestion is off topic a bit but I learned a whole lot about oauth by studying the mobile phone authentication example at Google FireBase. Also with a bit of help understanding JSON Web Tokens (JWT).  https://jwt.io/